# Highcharts - Visualizar gráfico de Ingresos y Egresos

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mi código:

```
SELECT   MONTHNAME(fecha), SUM(entrada), SUM(salida)
FROM     flujodecajas
WHERE    fecha BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-10-15'
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)
```

Obtengo los siguientes datos de la tabla:

```
MONTHNAME(fecha)  | sum(entrada)     | sum(salida)
------------------+------------------+------------------
September         | 50000.00         | 550.00
October           | 3398619.44       | 138349.60
```

En un archivo PHP ejecuto esa consulta, obtendo los datos, paso todo a JSON y lo envío por AJAX a un archivo JS que procesa los datos y realiza el gráfico con Highcharts.

El código de JS es:

```js
options = {
            chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container1',
                    type: 'column'
                   },
            title: {
                    text: 'Ingresos y Egresos'
                   },
            xAxis: {
                    type: "category"
                   },
            yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: true,
                    title: {
                            text: 'Dinero'
                           }
                    },
            tooltip: {

                    },  
            series: [
                     {
                        data:[]
                     }
                    ]
};
```

Obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: Gráfica obtenida con Highcharts]

Intenté diversas consultas pero no logro obtener la salida que deseo, que es:
En el eje X los meses, según la consulta, y en las barras, una que diga ingresos y otra egresos.

¿Alguna sugerencia?¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Fragmento en PHP.

```
$consulta = "SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha), sum(entrada), sum(salida) FROM flujodecajas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$fecInicio' AND '$fecFin' GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)";
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado->execute();
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  
array_push($result, array($fila["MONTHNAME(fecha)"], $fila["sum(entrada)"], $fila["sum(salida)"]));         
}
 print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Answer (score 1):

En la opciones de data debes agregar el campo de ingreso y egreso, algo así:

```
series: [{ name: 'Ingresos',
           data:[50000.00, 3398619.44]
         },{name: 'Egresos',
            data: [550.00, 138349.60]
         }]
```

fíjate en este ejemplo para que lo comprendas mejor: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

---

**EDIT:**

En ese caso, supongamos que tienes este formulario:

```
<div id="form_fechas">
   <input type="date" id="fecha_inicio">
   <input type="date" id="fecha_final">
   // boton
   <input type="button" id="boton">
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

// actualizas el gráfico de esta manera

```
// Cuando se presiona el botón
$('#boton').click(function(){
   var fecha_inicio = $('#fecha_inicio').val(),
      fecha_final   = $('#fecha_final').val();
     getData(fecha_inicio, fecha_final);
});

// esta función obtiene la información desde el php y actualiza el gráfico
function getData(fecha_inicio, fecha_final) {
  $.getJSON( "data/data-basic-colm-ajax.php", { fecha_inicio: fecha_inicio, fecha_final: fecha_final}, function(json) {
     options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; //xAxis: {categories: []}
     options.series[0] = json[1]['series'];                        
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
}
```

Ahora solo debes ordenar el PHP y obtener los valores con la variable `json`

Comment: Claro, de esa forma funciona, el tema es que los datos vienen desde un PHP en formato json, y mi sistema permite ingresar el rango de fechas, por lo que la consulta va a variar.

Comment: he editado mi respuesta, creo que eso es lo que buscas.

Comment: edité mi pregunta, adjunté el fragmento en PHP.

Comment: @Gustavo, ¿esta pregunta solucionó tu problema? si es así, recuerda [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Hola, no era lo que buscaba exactamente, por supuesto agradezco la ayuda. Finalmente, la solución era cambiar esta línea... while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
               array_push($result, array($fila["MONTHNAME(fecha)"], $fila["sum(totalVenta)"]));         
            }